# FullCalendar with ReactJS: Passing data to Modal on eventClick getting "cannot read property of undefined" Advice appreciated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar, axios, material-ui

I have a MERN stack application using the FullCalendar plugin (I know I'm asking for it mixing jQuery w React but alas, I am novice and far behind deadline).

I want the user to click on an event on the calendar and see a modal with that specific events information.

The issue is I can't access the specific events information from the FullCalendar plugins eventClick. The console informs me that it cannot read property of undefined.

Is it possible to access this data in the Modal? I am not 100% clear on how the plugin parses the data it is passed through state, so maybe that is the issue? Or perhaps I am missing an opportunity to bind?

If I set state to

```
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
event: {title: '', start: new Date()}
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

and then (in FullCalendar)

```
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
events={[{ title: "Event 1", date: "2020-01-01" }
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

I have no issue accessing the title of the event like so

```
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
{this.state.event.title}
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

But when I set state to

```
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
event: []
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

and use an axios.get request to set state to the db response like this

```
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
axios.get('/events')
  .then(response => {
    this.setState({event: response.data})
})
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

and set (in FullCalendar)

```
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
events={this.state.event}
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

the Calendar renders properly, but when I attempt to access the title

```
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
{this.state.event.title}
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

it cannot read property of undefined.

If I try {this.state.calendarEvents[0].title} it returns the title of only the first event object in the db. I think this is because calendarEvents is a js object containing all of the event objects in the db. Unfortunately I don't know how to remedy this issue.

I tried using eventSource in FullCalendar to feed the calendar data, but realized the data I'm passing is a js object, not a json feed. I believe FullCalendar has a method for parsing this object into the proper data while rendering the calendar, but I'm not sure how that helps me.

```js
    import React from "react";
    import FullCalendar from "@fullcalendar/react";
    import dayGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/daygrid";
    import timeGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/timegrid";
    import interactionPlugin from "@fullcalendar/interaction";
    import { Button, Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter } from "reactstrap";
    import axios from 'axios';
    import "../main.scss";

    import "@fullcalendar/core/main.css";
    import "@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css";
    import "@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.css";


    export default class CalendarView extends React.Component {
      calendarComponentRef = React.createRef();

      state = {
        modal: false,
        calendarWeekends: true,
        event: []
      };

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('/events')
          .then(response => {
            this.setState({event: response.data})
            console.log({calendarEvents: response.data})
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          })
      }

      toggle = () => {
        this.setState({ modal: !this.state.modal });
      };

      handleEventClick = ({ event, el }) => {
        this.toggle();
        this.setState({ event });
      };

      render() {
        return (
          <div className="cal-container">
            <div style={{marginTop: 30}}>
              <FullCalendar
                defaultView="timeGridDay"
                header={{
                  left: "prev,next today",
                  center: "title",
                  right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek"
                }}
                plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
                ref={this.calendarComponentRef}
                weekends={this.state.calendarWeekends}
                events={this.state.event}
                eventClick={this.handleEventClick}
                nowIndicator='true'
                height='parent'
              />
              <Modal
              isOpen={this.state.modal}
              toggle={this.toggle}
            >
              <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}>
                EVENT TITLE SHOULD GO HERE: {this.state.event.title}
              </ModalHeader>
              <ModalBody>
                <div>
                  EVENT INFO SHOULD GO HERE: {this.state.event.start}
                </div>
              </ModalBody>
              <ModalFooter>
                <Button color="primary">Do Something</Button>{" "}
                <Button color="secondary" onClick={this.toggle}>
                  Cancel
                </Button>
              </ModalFooter>
            </Modal>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

I expect the modal to show EVENT TITLE SHOULD GO HERE: Event 1 but instead it breaks and the console says "Cannot read property 'title' of undefined"

Any advice, insight, guidance is greatly appreciated.

If you read to the end, I'm already grateful for your time. Thanks!

Comment: "I know I'm asking for it mixing jQuery w React" ....I see no jQuery here. fullCalendar 4 doesn't use jQuery.

Comment: I am also confused by references in your question text to `this.state.calendarEvents` because this is not used anywhere in your code. Did you rename your variable at some point? Make sure your question matches your code please, or else it gets very difficult to be sure what you are talking about.

Comment: Anyway, I can see you seem to be re-using the same `state.event` variable to represent both the array of events you pass to fullCalendar initially, **and** the single clicked event. I'm not a React dev so I don't know if that's the cause of your issue but it's generally bad practice to use the same variable for two different purposes. You probably want to define something separate to hold the clicked event.

Answer (score 0):

Your `setState({event})` is being called after the modal has rendered. You need to delay the modal render, so that event object is set before display.

```
handleEventClick = ({ event, el }) => {
        this.setState({event: event, modal: true})
      };
```

This will ensure your event is set when modal is visible.